# why there is no ending tag in xml received by the Soap web service?

Tags: android, xml, soap

I am using the Ksoap2 library for the Soap web service as there is no direct way in android to do so. After using that I am successful to get the reply from the server. It has the starting tag "" and the xml response shouls also end with this tag. But I am getting no ending tag. here is what I am getting .

```
<NewDataSet>
<Table>
<AgentHangup>true</AgentHangup>
<CallDetailId>140120151439395690100016</CallDetailId>
<CallID>3171B65415000200</CallID>
<CorrelatorId />
<CallDuration>9</CallDuration>
<EncryptedCall>false</EncryptedCall>
<CallDate>2015/01/14 14:39:39</CallDate>
<CalledBy>9010</CalledBy>
<CalledTo>9000</CalledTo>
<IsExternal>false</IsExternal>
<RecorderType>PRIMARY</RecorderType>
<FirstName>fawad</FirstName>
<LastName>khan</LastName>
<Comments />
<FlagID>1</FlagID>
<FlagImage>1.gif</FlagImage>
<AF>C:\Program Files (x86)\Alcatel-Lucent\OmniPCXRecord Suite\OmniPCXRecord\OmniPCXRecordAudio\Repository\from\150114\0004\32_14012015 143939599_0016_9010.wav</AF>
<CallDirection>O</CallDirection>
<FLAGTEXT>Training required</FLAGTEXT>
<Archive>false</Archive>
<ExtensionValue>9010</ExtensionValue>
<GraphValue />
</Table>
<Table>
<AgentHangup>true</AgentHangup>
<CallDetailId>140120151439382290010016</CallDetailId>
<CallID>3171B65415000200</CallID>
<CorrelatorId />
<CallDuration>11</CallDuration>
<EncryptedCall>false</EncryptedCall>
<CallDate>2015/01/14 14:39:38</CallDate>
<CalledBy>9010</CalledBy>
<CalledTo>9001</CalledTo>
<IsExternal>false</IsExternal>
<RecorderType>PRIMARY</RecorderType>
<FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
<LastName>Rayan</LastName>
<Comments />
<FlagID>1</FlagID>
<FlagImage>1.gif</FlagImage>
<AF>C:\Program Files (x86)\Alcatel-Lucent\OmniPCXRecord Suite\OmniPCXRecord\OmniPCXRecordAudio\Repository\from\150114\0002\30_14012015 143938287_0016_9001.wav</AF>
<CallDirection>I</CallDirection>
<FLAGTEXT>Training required</FLAGTEXT>
<Archive>false</Archive>
<ExtensionValue>9001</ExtensionValue>
<GraphValue />
</Table>
<Table>
<AgentHangup>false</AgentHangup>
<CallDetailId>140120151439384490000016</CallDetailId>
<CallID>2A71B65414000200</CallID>
<CorrelatorId />
<CallDuration>11</CallDuration>
<EncryptedCall>false</EncryptedCall>
<CallDate>2015/01/14 14:39:38</CallDate>
<CalledBy>9010</CalledBy>
<CalledTo>9000</CalledTo>
<IsExternal>false</IsExternal>
<RecorderType>PRIMARY</RecorderType>
<FirstName>adnan</FirstName>
<LastName>akhtar</LastName>
<Comments />
<FlagID>1</FlagID>
<FlagImage>1.gif</FlagImage>
<AF>C:\Program Files (x86)\Alcatel-Lucent\OmniPCXRecord Suite\OmniPCXRecord\OmniPCXRecordAudio\Repository\from\150114\0001\31_14012015 143938537_0016_9000.wav</AF>
<CallDirection>I</CallDirection>
<FLAGTEXT>Training required</FLAGTEXT>
<Archive>false</Archive>
<ExtensionValue>9000</ExtensionValue>
<GraphValue />
</Table>
<Table>
<AgentHangup>false</AgentHangup>
<CallDetailId>140120151439354290010015</CallDetailId>
<CallID>3171B65415000200</CallID>
<CorrelatorId />
<CallDuration>1</CallDuration>
<EncryptedCall>false</EncryptedCall>
<CallDate>2015/01/14 14:39:35</CallDate>
<CalledBy>9010</CalledBy>
<CalledTo>9001</CalledTo>
<IsExternal>false</IsExternal>
<RecorderType>PRIMARY</RecorderType>
<FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
<LastName>Rayan</LastName>
<Comments />
<FlagID>1</FlagID>
<FlagImage>1.gif</FlagImage>
<AF>C:\Program Files (x86)\Alcatel-Lucent\OmniPCXRecord Suite\OmniPCXRecord\OmniPCXRecordAudio\Repository\from\150114\0002\28_14012015 143935505_0015_9001.wav</AF>
<CallDirection>I</CallDirection>
<FLAGTEXT>Training required</FLAGTEXT>
<Archive>false</Archive>
<ExtensionValue>9001</ExtensionValue>
<GraphValue />
</Table>
<Table>
<AgentHangup>true</AgentHangup>
<CallDetailId>140120151439355890100015</CallDetailId>
<CallID>3171B65415000200</CallID>
<CorrelatorId />
<CallDuration>2</CallDuration>
<EncryptedCall>false</EncryptedCall>
<CallDate>2015/01/14 14:39:35</CallDate>
<CalledBy>9010</CalledBy>
<CalledTo>9001</CalledTo>
<IsExternal>false</IsExternal>
<RecorderType>PRIMARY</RecorderType>
```

See there is no such ending tag that we have in starting (in this case NewDataSet)

I am using following class to get the response:

```
    public class SoapRequests {

    private static final boolean DEBUG_SOAP_REQUEST_RESPONSE = true;
    private static final String MAIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://192.168.2.152/OmniPCXRecord/recordservice.asmx";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static String SESSION_ID;
    public static String Toaster=null ;

    private final void testHttpResponse(HttpTransportSE ht) {
        ht.debug = DEBUG_SOAP_REQUEST_RESPONSE;
        if (DEBUG_SOAP_REQUEST_RESPONSE) {
            Log.v("SOAP RETURN", "Request XML:\n" + ht.requestDump);
            Log.v("SOAP RETURN", "\n\n\nResponse XML:\n" + ht.responseDump)
            ;
            Toaster=ht.responseDump;
        }
    }

    public String getData(String fValue) {
        String data = null;
        String methodname = "SearchCalls";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, methodname);
        //3
        request.addProperty("username", "admin");
        //
        request.addProperty("password", "admin");

        //5
        request.addProperty("FirstNameCriteria", "");
        //6
        request.addProperty("FirstName", "");
        //7
        request.addProperty("LastNameCriteria", "");
        //8
        request.addProperty("LastName", "");
        //9
        request.addProperty("GroupSearchOption", "");
        //10
        request.addProperty("GroupName", "");
        //11
        request.addProperty("EncryptedCallsCriteria", "");
        //12
        request.addProperty("AssociatedAgentCriteria", "");
        //13
        request.addProperty("CalledByCriteria", "");
        //14
        request.addProperty("CalledBy", "");
        //15
        request.addProperty("CalledToCriteria", "");
        //16
        request.addProperty("CalledTo", "");
        //17
        request.addProperty("CalledDateSearchCriteria", "Past_N_days");
        //18
        request.addProperty("NumberOfDays", "1");
        //19
        request.addProperty("StartDate", "");
        //20
       //I have round about 100 of parameters to send and they are generated successfully
       //i am sharing here few just for example
        Log.v("Final Property is",request.toString());




        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = getSoapSerializationEnvelope(request);

        HttpTransportSE ht = getHttpTransportSE();
        try {
            ht.call(SOAP_ACTION + methodname, envelope);
            testHttpResponse(ht);
            SoapPrimitive resultsString = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

            //   List<HeaderProperty> COOKIE_HEADER = (List<HeaderProperty>) ht.getServiceConnection().getResponseProperties();

//            for (int i = 0; i < COOKIE_HEADER.size(); i++) {
//                String key = COOKIE_HEADER.get(i).getKey();
//                String value = COOKIE_HEADER.get(i).getValue();
//
//                if (key != null && key.equalsIgnoreCase("set-cookie")) {
//                    SoapRequests.SESSION_ID = value.trim();
//                    Log.v("SOAP RETURNCookiee", "Cookie :" + SoapRequests.SESSION_ID+key);
//                   // Log.v("SOAP RETURNCookiee", "Cookie :" + SoapRequests.SESSION_ID);
//                    break;
//                }
//            }
            data = resultsString.toString();

        } catch (SocketTimeoutException t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception q) {
            q.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }

    private final SoapSerializationEnvelope getSoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapObject request) {
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        //change from orgnl
        //envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        return envelope;
    }

    private final HttpTransportSE getHttpTransportSE() {
        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(Proxy.NO_PROXY,MAIN_REQUEST_URL,6000);
        ht.debug = true;
        ht.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\" ?>");
        return ht;
    }

}
```

Notice that I am using this "SoapPrimitive resultsString = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();" for getting the response in string format. 
now tell me that why there is no ending tag in xml that i am getting in string format ? what Is problem? there is nothing in Log , every thing is fine.

Comment: It isn't missing just one closing tag. Note the Table tag 12 lines up from the bottom; that isn't closed either. It looks as if your XML is being truncated for some reason. Maybe it's running into an implementation limit.

Comment: please look again all the tables have ending tag except the ending one

Comment: also I have checked in the Log by Finding option, i first searched the opening table tag they were 5 in number and then I searched the closing tag they were 4 in number , so there is ending one missing if you see closely but there is also no ending tag of NewDataSet